# Use Ubuntu DNS Server instead of Windows

Tags: networking, server, dns

We have 2 Windows DNS server for our internal network, and over 120 Vlans.

I had a look at the config and found out that we have 6 reverse lookup zones (111.168.192.in-addr.arpa.dns, 0.in-addr.arpa.dns,127.in-addr.arpa.dns ,255.168.192.in-addr.arpa.dns, 255.in-addr.arpa.dns and 70.100.10.in-addr.arpa.dns).

I didn't configure this, the guy before me did it.

I would love to change from Windows DNS server to Ubuntu (2 servers), my question is:

Do I need to enter all 6 zones in the new servers? if yes,do I need then to create the `/etc/bind/db.xxx` file for each zone?

In case I need to use all 6 zones (without exporting from windows), could someone please help with this, as I've never done it before.what should I do with each of the following zones please:

(111.168.192.in-addr.arpa.dns,
0.in-addr.arpa.dns,
127.in-addr.arpa.dns ,
255.168.192.in-addr.arpa.dns,
255.in-addr.arpa.dns and
70.100.10.in-addr.arpa.dns).

Many thanks

Comment: Sorry for the delay in being unable to reply before, I had other projects at work and now it's the time to finish the DNS job, as December is relatively quite. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Bind by default has default empty zones for the private DNS blocks 10.0.0.0/8, 192.168.0.0/16 172.16.0.0/20.   You may want to create non-empty zones for the parts of the private networks you do have.  This seems to be 192.168.111.0/24 and 10.100.10.0/24.

The in-addr.arpa zones reverse the order of the octets in the address and omit the trailing zero octets. Sizing is still by octets so zones have 1, 2 or 3 octets in the address.

Install and configure bind along side your existing DNS until you are confident you have the correct configuration.  Check the configuration that is provided after you install bind and add the zones you need to that.

It may be possible to get a zone transfer from the exisitng configuration,  If not, it should be possible to script creating the reverse lookup zones by querying the existing active zones with a script.

Comment: You could allow transfer in your excisting DNS server, and run dig zone xfr > zonename.db - this will give you a copy. If you're running AD (which you probably do), you *really* have to be sure updating is working - as AD will fail in really spectacular ways if DNS is broken.

Comment: Many many thanks for all your help, you all are stars.